# Creating multiple log files from child processes in multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-logging

I am in a situation where my Python application can process up to 500k jobs at a time. To accomplish this we use a `multiprocessing.Pool` in the following manner:

```py
# make the Pool of workers
pool = multiprocessing.get_context('spawn').Pool(num_processors)

# create the arg set used by the workers
argumentSet = []
for job in jobs:
        argumentSet.append((job, output_dir))

pool.starmap(foo_bar, argumentSet)
```

We need to support customized logging for our users. Since we are processing so many jobs at a time, ideally I'd like to have each child process (or 'worker') of the pool create 1 log file that logs all of the different jobs it processes. That way we don't write 500k log files or 1 massive log files to disk, making it impossible to read and understand where things went wrong.

My initial idea was to pass the logger object instantiated in the parent process as an argument to the child process:

```py
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
argumentSet = []
for job in jobs:
        argumentSet.append((job, output_dir, root_logger))
```

But my question is what configurations would I need to add in `foo_bar` to ensure that each child process writes to its own log file?

If this approach isn't optimal, I am open to trying anything else!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimalistic example of how to create individual log files for each spawned process:

```
import logging
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process

logging.basicConfig(filename='master.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info('Master begin')

def f(a):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    for h in logger.handlers:
        logger.removeHandler(h)
    h = logging.FileHandler('worker_{}.log'.format(current_process().pid))
    logger.addHandler(h)
    logging.info(f'a = {a}')

p = Pool()
p.map(f, [1, 2, 3, 4])
logging.info('Master end')
```

The above creates five log files: One master and four child logs. Note how each child process manipulates logging in the beginning of the spawned function just before logging a message.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a *pool initializer* to initialize a log for each specific pool processor *once*. To ensure unique names you could use the current process id, but these change on successive runs. It might be better to just use incrementing integers so that on successive runs you can be sure the existing logs are being appended (if you want to start out with new, empty logs, then just delete before you begin `Log1.log`, `Log2.log` ... `LogN.log` where the pool size is `N`):

```py
import logging
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value

def init_pool_processes(log_number):
    with log_number.get_lock():
        log_number.value += 1
        this_log = log_number.value

    logging.basicConfig(filename=f'Log{this_log}.log', level=logging.INFO)

def f(x):
    import time

    # Simulate doing some work:
    time.sleep(.1)

    logging.info('%d ** 2 = %d', x, x * x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_number = Value('i', 0)
    with Pool(4, initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(log_number,)) as pool:
        pool.map(f, range(100))
```